# Host asp.net and angular app as separate sub-sites on azure app service

Tags: asp.net, angular, azure-web-app-service

I have a scenario where I have an asp.net site with HTTP modules. I have another app built in angular 5 which needs to be hosted as a subsite of this site(This is plain angular).

I have tried deploying the site as an application in Azure app service. The subsite fails to load giving an error that it failed to load the HTTP modules. Is there a way to fix the issue for azure app service

I have tried setting the value `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"` but I does not fix the issue.

Comment: What is the error message that you see?

Comment: And which modules are failing to load?